# TFS Local Path Mapping and Shared Files - Custom Rule Set

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015

We are trying to implement a custom rule set and we have stored it in a folder in TFS outside our project folders (see below). Problem is, our developers start their local path map at a different folder. We don't have a consistent policy for ensuring all developers start their mapping at the DefaultCollection level. Some start it at DevelopmentArea as an example for different reasons. So, a couple of questions:

- Do folks out there have a consistent mapping policy for all your developers?
- Should we store the rule set files in some shared server folder instead of mandating developers get latest from TFS which then causes mapping issues with the relative path of the rule set file in the csproj settings?

tfs.server.com\DefaultCollection
----- DevelopmentArea

----------    Projects

----------------       Project1

----------------       Project2

----------    RuleSets

Answer (score 0):

For question1:

There isn't a consistent mapping policy there, everyone can customize map the local path.
You must mention them if you want all of the developers start their local path map same as the repository structure.

For question2:

Yes you can store the rule set files to a shared folder to avoid causing mapping issues. The files can be in source control.

1. Create a share folder
2. Map the source files (RuleSets) to share folder
3. Specify the rule set file path for you project in VS (Right click the project > properties > Code Analysis > Rule Set)

In this way you can manage the rule set files with south control.